# Generate a random population

Tags: r, sample

I am having an issue with my code and I am not sure on how to adjust it. Basically, the goal is to have 1 initial infected  in one patch. There are three patches and with sample(), I am trying to have that infected be randomized into one of the three patches on each run. However with the current code, I am sometimes having two initial infected and I am not sure how to prevent that from happening.

```r
patchPopSize <- c(50, 50, 50)       # Size of each patch (pop size in a patch)

U <- length(patchPopSize)           # Number of patches (metapopulation size)

initial_infected <- sample(0:1, U, replace = TRUE) # Initial infected (1 in patch 1, 0 in the others)
```

I also have this bit of code that has to do with the initial parameters, but I haven't changed it at all so not sure of the issue is within this set of the code or previous

```r
for (i in 1:U) {
  x0_list[[i]] <- c(patchPopSize[i] - initial_infected[i], 0, initial_infected[i], 0, patchPopSize[i])
}
```

I have tried changing the initial infected by breaking up the code and doing it in steps, but it stops after two runs. Not sure if using random() may work better

Comment: I am a bit unclear on what you are asking, but in your `sample` statement you are sampling `c(0, 1)` three times with replacement , so you have a probability of sampling all the combinations (ie: 110, 101, 001, 000, etc). If you  want to sample exactly one 1 (ie, 100, 010, 001), try `sample(c(rep(0, U - 1), 1), U)`